# Intersection of localizations

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, not necessarily a domain, and let $S_i$ be a family of multiplicative closed subsets of $R$. What is the exact meaning of $\bigcap_i S_i^{-1}R$?

For example, for an integral domain $R$, it is well known that for two prime ideals $p_1$ and $p_2$ of $R$, we have $R_{p_1}\cap R_{p_2}=R_{p_1\cup p_2}$.

Comment: $S = \bigcap_i S_i$ is trivially also multiplicative and my guess would be that it is just $S^{-1}R$.

Comment: I think he meant $\bigcap_i (S_i^{-1}R)$. But then I wonder if there's a canonical ring where you can map every $S_i^{-1}R$ if $R$ has i.e. zero-divisors.

Comment: I think this intersection is only meaningful if $R$ is a domain (in which case you can take the intersection in the field of fractions) or the $S_i$ are guaranteed not to consist of zero divisors (in which case you can take this intersection in the "total ring of fractions," where you invert all non-zero divisors).